# React Redux Axios - Props can be accessed then goes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

Overview: I make a GET request through Axios (in this case it's a mock adapter) and have it update my store through dispatch. The mock adapter will send back the same response as long as the path is '/posts/*'.

The peculiar thing is that it actually displays the props that is from the mock API (for 1 second), but then it goes to prop is undefined (i.e. Cannot read property 'title' of undefined).

When I log this.props, it shows that those props do exist. So I don't think anything changed them back to null.

Here is the axios part, which I currently put in the apiMiddleware function in my middleware.js

```
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_POST_AXIOS' });
        let { postID } = action.payload;
        mock.onGet(API_BASE + "/posts/" + postID).reply(200, {
          post:
            { id: 1,
              title: 'Test Title',
              description: 'Test Description',
              media: { medium_url: "http://test.com/test.jpg" }
            }
        });
        axios({
            url: API_BASE + "/posts/" + postID,
            timeout: 20000,
            method: 'get',
            responseType: 'json'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
                dispatch({ type: 'SERVE_POST_AXIOS', response: response.data });
            })
```

Here is the reducer part

```
case 'SERVE_POST_AXIOS':
  return Object.assign({}, state, { post_axios: response.post })
```

And this is in my mapDispatchToProps in the component that renders the post. The match.params is from react-router's BrowserRouter.

```
loadFromAxios(cb) {
    console.log("Load from Axios called..");
    dispatch({ type: 'API', payload: { success: 'GET_POST_AXIOS', postID: ownProps.match.params.postID } });
        cb();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying my conditional, which was intially

```
this.state.loading ? 
<div>Loading</div>
:
<div>Info here with props</div>
```

into

```
this.props.post ?
<div>Info here with props</div>
:
<div>Loading</div>
```

But I'd very much like to do this with the current way through `this.state.loading`. Anyone have an idea?

I start with defining this.state.loading as false, then this is my ComponentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadFromAxios( () => this.setState({ loading: false }) );
}
```

Why does this not work?